# You Tube API: Ordering Playlists

Tags: youtube-api

Does the You Tube API return any values which would allow you to control the order playlists are displayed in? I know you can control the order videos are displayed in within individual playlists, but can the order of the playlists themselves be controlled?

Answer (score 0):

Basic testing seems to indicate that a playlists feed (whether it be a search, a collection of users' lists, etc.) doesn't like the 'orderby' parameter at all, so unless there is some other undocumented function that someone else can comment on, the API feed itself can't do any ordering.

Depending on your client, however, it should be pretty straightforward to do ordering in your language of choice; for example, in the Python gdata client (using APIv3), the playlists are returned as the 'items' list, and so any list functions will work on it, including custom sort functions. If you indicate the language you're working with, someone could likely help figure out a simple sorting function with you.